# Not able to run Lottie animations on PyQt5 QML

Tags: pyqt5, qml, qt-creator, lottie, bodymovin

Downloaded a bunch of lottie animations from https://lottiefiles.com.

Trying to run these lottie animations on PyQt5 QML and i get an error on Qt Creator:

`qt.lottieqt.bodymovin.parser: assets not supported`

`qt.lottieqt.bodymovin.parser: Unsupported layer type: 0`

`qt.lottieqt.bodymovin.parser: Unsupported layer type: 1`

`qt.lottieqt.bodymovin.parser: Unsupported layer type: 2`

`QColor::setRgbF: Alpha parameter is out of range`

And many more issues...

Is there any explanations for this because i couldn't find anything online

for example:

1 Lottie animation worked was: https://assets9.lottiefiles.com/temp/lf20_7rPCHc.json

and that's the only one that worked

lottie animation that didn't work is: https://assets9.lottiefiles.com/datafiles/WFKIUGAVvLl1azi/data.json

Comment: Have you checked if those features supported on this page? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtlottieanimation-index.html#limitations

Comment: @Mitch okay so it does have limitations.... the link you.ve sent is for Qt6.3 but i managed to find the QT5.15.2 and it also has limitations too. Thanks, any other library that renders lottie animations on python other than Qt?